# Select channel from multiplexer to show temperature values in c programming

Tags: c

I'm trying to receive some temperature reading from the two sensors which shared the same address and while I'm using one sensor, it can work perfectly. However, when I tried to fix the second sensor onto the circuit and edit the program abit, it doesn't work.

Here's the code when the sensor is reading:

```
void readSensor(void) {
int ch;
TWI_init_master();
//TWI_start();
for (ch=0; ch<2; ch++) 
{

    TWI_start();
    TWI_write_address(0xE0); // set multiplixer
    TWI_write_data(0x00); // disable all ch
    TWI_write_data(0x01); // enable  ch-ch+1
    TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_write_address(0x14);// writing to sensor
    TWI_write_data(0x4C);// asking for data
    TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_read_address(0x15);// read

    /*For ch 2 to read
    TWI_write_data(ch+1); // enable  ch
    TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_write_data (0xE1); // enable read
    TWI_write_address(0x14);// writing to sensor
    TWI_write_data(0x4C);// asking for data
    TWI_repeated_start(); //restart
    TWI_read_address(0x15);// read
    */


    if (ch==0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
        TWI_read_data();//geting data
        readbuff[i] = recv_data;
        }

        if(!(D6T_checkPEC(readbuff, 34))) {
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 2; i < 34; i++) 
            {

                temp = readbuff[i];
                writeChar(temp, USB);
                delay10ms(10);
            }                       
        }
    }
    else if (ch==1) 
    {

        for(j = 36; j < 67; j++) {
            TWI_read_data();//geting data
            readbuff[j] = recv_data;
            }

        if(!D6T_checkPEC(readbuff, 66)) {
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
        }
        else
        {
            for(j = 2; j < 66; j++) 
            {
                temp = readbuff[j];
                writeChar(temp, USB);
                delay10ms(10);  
            }
        }
    }
    TWI_stop();
    delay10ms(10);  
    //TWI_repeated_start();// restart
}
TWI_stop(); }
```

The multiplexer datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pca9548a.pdf
I hope someone can help me to see what's wrong with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the datasheet: " When a channel is selected, the channel becomes active after a stop condition has been placed on the I2C bus." However, it appears you are not sending a STOP after the command to the mux but instead are using a repeated-START. Therefore, the mux is not switching until the very end where you call `TWI_stop`.

You should probably replace the `TWI_repeated_start` (which is after the mux writes) with a `TWI_stop`, followed by a `TWI_start`. <del>You also need a `TWI_stop` after the sensor read.</del>

Edit: Here's your code with my proposed changes.

```
void readSensor(void) {
int ch;
TWI_init_master();
//TWI_start();
for (ch=0; ch<2; ch++) 
{

    TWI_start();
    TWI_write_address(0xE0); // set multiplixer
    TWI_write_data(0x00); // disable all ch
    TWI_write_data(0x01); // enable  ch-ch+1
    // **REMOVED** TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_stop();  // **NEW** Mux switches on STOP condition
    TWI_start(); // **NEW**
    TWI_write_address(0x14);// writing to sensor
    TWI_write_data(0x4C);// asking for data
    TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_read_address(0x15);// read

    /*For ch 2 to read
    TWI_write_data(ch+1); // enable  ch
    TWI_repeated_start();// restart
    TWI_write_data (0xE1); // enable read
    TWI_write_address(0x14);// writing to sensor
    TWI_write_data(0x4C);// asking for data
    TWI_repeated_start(); //restart
    TWI_read_address(0x15);// read
    */


    if (ch==0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            TWI_read_data();//geting data
            readbuff[i] = recv_data;
        }

        if(!(D6T_checkPEC(readbuff, 34))) {
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 2; i < 34; i++) 
            {

                temp = readbuff[i];
                writeChar(temp, USB);
                delay10ms(10);
            }                       
        }
    }
    else if (ch==1) 
    {

        for(j = 36; j < 67; j++) {
            TWI_read_data();//geting data
            readbuff[j] = recv_data;
            }

        if(!D6T_checkPEC(readbuff, 66)) {
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
            writeChar(0x50, USB);
        }
        else
        {
            for(j = 2; j < 66; j++) 
            {
                temp = readbuff[j];
                writeChar(temp, USB);
                delay10ms(10);  
            }
        }
    }
    TWI_stop();
    delay10ms(10);  
    //TWI_repeated_start();// restart
}
TWI_stop(); }
```

Comment: Do you mean by TWI_start();
  TWI_write_address(0xE0); // set multiplixer
  TWI_write_data(0); // disable all ch
  TWI_write_data(ch+1); // enable  ch-ch+1
  TWI_stop();
  TWI_start();
 // TWI_repeated_start();// restart
  TWI_write_address(0x14);// writing to sensor
  TWI_write_data(0x4C);// asking for data
  TWI_repeated_start();// restart
  TWI_read_address(0x15);// read

Comment: As you can see, code in a comment is basically unreadable. I've edited my answer to show the code with my changes.

Comment: Yes I have done what you have said but it is still couldn't able to see the results. I wonder why too. As my data will be shown in the real term program.

Comment: The only other thing I can come up with would be electrical. For example, are you sure that the address pins are all grounded to give the E0 address?

Comment: I have shown the diagram which states the address pins and the pins connection also stated that A0-2 are grounded.

Comment: It stated that it can be connected to either Vcc or ground for A0-A2 and I have also connected the RESET to Vcc as well.

Answer (score 0):

![The slave address is fixed for the first 4][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEplE.jpg

I see the diagram from here. 1110 and I set A2,A1,A0 as low (0).

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing else. Assuming that your TWI_ functions do what their names indicate and your schematic is correct, I think it should work. I'd suggest reopening your question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ (linking back to this question) and include the schematic.